# html heading issue with where to place it

Tags: html

I am trying to get my html website page to have the "Most Beautiful Theorem?" section on the right side. However, I can't figure out how to do that. Right now it is just showing up under all my other headings like normal but I want it on the right side of the page as a separate column. If you could help me that would be great. Thanks! 
here's the coding I have now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- Math High home page 
McLain-Graning MaKayla, CSIS 140, Fall 2015
-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Math High</title>
<link href="css/MathHighStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<img src="images_MathHigh/mhlogo.jpg" alt="Math High"/>
<h2>Leonhard Euler (1707-1783)</h2>
</header>
<section>
<article>
<p>
The greatest mathematician of the eighteenth century, 
<strong>Leonhard Euler</strong> was born in Basel, Switzerland. There, 
he studied under another giant of mathematics, <strong>Jean 
Bernoulli</strong>. In 1731 Euler became a professor of physics 
and mathematics at St. Petersburg Academy of Sciences. 
Euler was the most prolific mathematician of all time, 
publishing over 800 different books and papers. His 
influence was felt in physics and astronomy as well.
</p>
</article>
<p>
He is perhaps best known for his research into 
mathematical analysis. Euler's work, 
Introductio in analysin infinitorum (1748), 
remained a standard textbook in the field for 
well over a century. For the princess of Anhalt-Dessau he wrote 
Lettres a une princesse d'Allemagne (1768-1772), 
giving a clear non-technical outline of the main 
physical theories of the time.
</p>
<p>
One can hardly write a mathematical equation without 
copying Euler. Notations still in use today, such 
as e and pi, were introduced 
in Euler's writings. Leonhard Euler died in 1783, 
leaving behind a legacy perhaps unmatched, and 
certainly unsurpassed, in the annals of mathematics.
</p>
</section>
<aside>
<h1>The Most Beautiful Theorem?</h1>
<p>Euler's Equation:</p>
<p>cos(x) + i*sin(x) = e to the power (i*x)</p>
<p>demonstrates the relationship between algebra, 
complex analysis, and trigonometry. From this 
equation, it's easy to derive the identity:
</p>
<p>e to the power (pi*i) + 1 = 0</p>
<p>which relates the fundamental constants: 
0, 1, pi, e, and i in a single beautiful and 
elegant statement. A poll of readers 
conducted by The Mathematical Intelligencer
magazine named Euler's Identity as the 
most beautiful theorem in the history of 
mathematics.</p>
<p>Math High: A Site for Educators and Researchers</p>
</aside>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where's the css that you've tried?

Comment: if I use css then how would I move it to the right and put a background behind it? I know this probably sounds super easy...but the teachers at my school are super awful and can't teach the basics.

Comment: if you give to "section" width:70% , float:left and "aside" width:30% float: right then it might look the way you want it

Comment: Thank you so much for you comment it truly helped. And like I said...it was super easy....

Comment: Add a identifier attribute to your desired header and use css positions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the h1 element an id or a class name and add a CSS style to make the heading float.
See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp